# Meteor Accounts reset password token is always null

Tags: meteor, token, reset-password

Looking at the source code of `url_client.js` it clearly states that

```
    // reset password urls use hash fragments instead of url paths/query
    // strings so that the reset password token is not sent over the wire
    // on the http request
```

I am using [mini-pages](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-mini-pages) which doesn't use hash fragments in the url's and so my reset password token is never set.

I have a mini pages route set up to handle the following path : 'reset-password/:code'

```
match = window.location.hash.match(/^\#\/reset-password\/(.*)$/);
```

The hash match always returns null, what can i do to get the token ? I thought the token was stored in the database and shouldn't meteor validate against the database before setting the reset password token

The accounts-urls package defines helpers that look for the '#' in the front and my url is never caught for some reason.

```
  Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function (token) {
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl('#/reset-password/' + token);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do... The token is send to the user by mail, to get it you just have to read it from the url hash (which is what the code you provide does).

Comment: Your first statement is already working for me. The token on deployment is sent to the user's email and when running locally is sent to the terminal as output. The issue is after browsing to the provided url, match is null because instead of expecting #reset-password/code the '#' is missing

Comment: On the server or on the client?

Comment: this is on the client. I check if Accounts._resetPasswordToken is available and it never is because match couldn't find anything. I may also be looking for the token in the wrong place but i have looked for it in several of my templates using the 'rendered' call back with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wanting to know. This was caused by the html5history API package that comes with the meteor-router or mini-router meteorite packages. I removed them and the tokens are no longer null